# Passing HTML select dropdown value to PHP variable using post only passed the first word on the string

Tags: php, html

I have  HTML element that is populated with a patient's first name and last name there is a space between them. When posting the selected value to a separate php file the value passed is only ever the first name of the string instead of the whole name. How would I change this to pass the full name.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "connection.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="patients.css" />
  <script defer src="modals.js"></script>
  <title>Patients</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <button data-modal-target='#modal1'>Add Patient</button>
    <h1>Patients</h1>
    <button data-modal-target='#modal2'>Edit Patient</button>
  </nav>

  <div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <h2>Add Patient</h2>
    <h3>Enter Patient Information</h3>
    <form action="process-patient.php" method="post">
      <p>First Name</p>
      <input name="Firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter first name here">
      <p>Last Name</p>
      <input name="Lastname" type="text" placeholder="Enter last name here">
      <p>Email Address</p>
      <input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email here">
      <p>Phone Number</p>
      <input name="Phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone number here">
      <p>Reason for Admition</p>
      <input name="Reason" type="text" placeholder="Enter reason for admition">
      <div class="button-container">
        <button data-close-button class="close-button" type="button">Close</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal" id="modal2">
    <h2>Edit Patient</h2>
    <h3>Modify Patient Information</h3>
    <form action="edit-patient.php" method="post">
      <p>Select Patient</p>
      <select name="Patients">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT concat(Firstname , ' ' ,Lastname) AS Name FROM patients;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<option   value=\"' . $row['Name'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
        }

        echo "</select>";
        ?>
        <p>First Name</p>
        <input name="Firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter first name here">
        <p>Last Name</p>
        <input name="Lastname" type="text" placeholder="Enter last name here">
        <p>Email Address</p>
        <input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email here">
        <p>Phone Number</p>
        <input name="Phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone number here">
        <p>Reason for Admition</p>
        <input name="Reason" type="text" placeholder="Enter reason for admition">
        <div class="button-container">
          <button data-close-button class="close-button" type="button">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" name="discharge-button">Discharge</button>
          <button type="submit" name="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>

  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>PhoneNumber</th>
          <th>Admitted</th>
          <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row["Firstname"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Lastname"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Email"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Phonenumber"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Admitted"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Reason"] . "</td>
      </tr>";
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <a class="home" href="home.php">Home</a>
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) : ?>
    <a class="logout" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
  <?php endif ?>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  require_once "connection.php";

  if (isset($_POST["discharge-button"])) {
    $patient = $_POST["Patients"];
    echo $_POST["Patients"];
    /*
    $sql = "DELETE FROM patients WHERE Firstname = '$fname' && Lastname = '$lname';";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    /*echo "Patient discharged successfully";

    $conn = null;
    $stmt = null;*/
    exit();
  } else {
    die();
  }
}
```

I've seen people on here have a problem like this when trying to populate the drop down with two names but I can't find anything for when you pass it over.

Comment: Not sure what database you are using, so will assume MySQL. If so, you may wish to use CONCAT_WS rather than CONCAT.

Comment: What do you see when the script executes the line `echo $_POST["Patients"];` ?

Comment: I am using MySQL the table populates correctly with all of the names from the database when selecting the name in the drop down "Jane Smith" the echo $_POST["Patients"]; returns "Jane"

Comment: I have now also tried encoding it with htmlSpecialChars before inserting into the table and decoing afterwards but still didnt work

Comment: The code you posted will not cause what you said. (most likely you have other code causing the $_POST["Patients"] to be 'Jane' )

Comment: When using concat_ws instaed of concat the names are displayed without the space in the drop down then when passing the varaible to the php file the variable then returns empty

Comment: I updated with the test of the html page im not sure what else could affect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you just need to change line

```
echo '<option   value=\"' . $row['Name'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
```

to

```
echo '<option   value="' . $row['Name'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
```

(not escaping the opening double quote after "value").

Before that you should see what the mistake did in browser console, your HTML should change from

```
<option value=\"Jane Smith">Jane Smith</option>
```

to

```
<option value="Jane Smith">Jane Smith</option>
```

which is valid (you can even notice the coloring of the code here).